# Verify if user is registered through an email in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When an user signs up on my site, I call `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` and their user has successfully been created.

I basically want a "Do I have an account" on my page. If they enter their e-mail address, it should send a request to Firebase with ONLY their e-mail, and Firebase should then return with true/false (or something similar).

A "workaround" I have found is trying to create an user or simply signing into Firebase with an empty password. I assume Firebase would return "wrong password" (meaning they have an account). `firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail("some@email.com")` could also work, but I haven't been able to figure out how it works.

Alternatively I store all emails in an array. Push to that array when a new user signs up, but that seems very insecure and like a lot of work (as I don't think you can just push an email and forget the ID, basically making it impossible to iterate through all emails).

Here's what I have come up with that works:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.username, " ").catch(function(error) {
    if(error.code === "auth/wrong-password") {
        console.log("USER HAS AN ACCOUNT");
    } else if(error.code === "auth/user-not-found"){
        console.log("NEW USER");
    }
});
```

Simply sign in with a password that doesn't work.

Comment: FWIW "do I have an account" is generally not the best security practice. The way someone should figure out if they have an account is by successfully logging in or failing to do so. Otherwise, bad actors can use the "do I have an account" feature to determine users of your app and (in worst-case scenarios) devise spear-phishing campaigns based on your service.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I don't need a lecture on account security. Thanks for your concerns, though.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Sorry if that came out rude. That was not my intention :) I'm trying out a new authentication system (almost like Microsoft), where you start entering your email address, then it checks whether or not you have an user on blur.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I see you're a Firebase Engineer. Do you know if this is possible at all? :)

Comment: You could store the email in the firebase database when the user signs up.

Comment: @Lirianer That's what I said in the last paragraph, however, that doesn't seem very reliable. I would have to keep that list synchronized.

Comment: You can just push the email and forget about the id. Then you make a query orderByChild('email').equalTo(inputEmail)

The only concern is the security of the email list

Comment: @Lirianer How would you push a single email though? I haven't been able to discard the id when using push. Only when I use set I am able to do it.

Comment: You don't need to discard it

Comment: @Lirianer How am I able to do it then? I did try with `orderByChild("email").equalTo("some@email")` and got nothing. Nonetheless, that's not the way to do it.

Comment: I know it's been said but that is the absolute worst idea ever. No offense, but it literally creates a way for hackers to know if emails are in use. I would highly highly suggest not doing that. Not "giving you a lecture" either just saying the obvious here.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm Microsoft does this though? Facebook does it? Basically every site that says "No account associated with this email" has this implemented. Try logging into Facebook with a wrong email. Got an `The email you've entered doesn't match any account` error? Yeah, this would work the exact same way.

Comment: Microsoft and Facebook aren't necessarily the standard for what you should do. Furthermore, Microsoft and Facebook probably have the security measures in place to be able to thwart any attack. Something that a team of thousands of engineers would be able to accomplish, while you might be a great programmer, wouldn't. Your point is duly taken though, if they do that, then that's horrible practice on their part. Either way, I'll stop disturbing your thread. Good luck!

Comment: Firebase does give an error of user not found now that I have gave it a look https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm How are they able to handle such "attack" if I can't? I'm more than capable of securing my site from attackers :)

Comment: Because they have a team of thousands of network and security engineers with Stanford and MIT degrees? Idk, just saying, bad practice to look up by email.

Comment: Still, firebase does give an error if the user is not found so you could use that to check if the email is registered.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm And what can they do that I can't? If someone brute forces an account -> Captcha that IP and flag the account as being "brute forced". If someone else from another IP tries to log in to that account, they get 1 attempt and then captcha strikes again. After a few captcha tries and still unsuccessful, I ban the IP from logging in for 30-60 minutes. That to me is more secure than any I've seen so far.

Comment: @Lirianer No offense, but do you only read the comments? Read my post and you will see I've already done that.

Comment: Dude.. Yes I read the other comments, that tell you not to do what you're trying to do just like me. Perhaps you should take heed to advice and not do it that way. I mean, how many signs do you need?

Comment: Yep, that part is new. It wasn't there when I came. I find that is the best solution you could have.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm I was talking to Lirianer :) How many signs I need? None. I don't see how this turned into a discussion about security. Did I ever ask a question about security? No. Did I even mention security? No. Why bring up something completely unrelated to my question, just because **YOU** think it's worth mentioning? As I said in my very first comment: `I don't need a lecture on account security`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you might approach it: when a user first signs up, encode their email in a key-friendly way and stick it in the Realtime Database:

```
firebase.database().ref('accountCheck')
  .child(user.email.replace(/\./g, '%2E')).set(true)
```

Then write security rules such that the list of emails can be accessed individually but not collectively:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "accountCheck": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false,
      "$encoded": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "$encoded === auth.token.email.replace('.', '%2E') && newData.val() === true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now your blur check would be to take the value of the input and see if it exists in the DB:

```
firebase.database().ref('accountCheck')
  .child(input.value.replace(/\./g, '%2E'))
  .once('value').then(snap => {
    if (snap.exists()) {
      // account exists
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi, Michael! Thanks a lot for the suggestion. If I do this, I would have to sync the list with users and emails, right? I assume this is the only other way, except doing it like I posted at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Yep, those are the only two ways I can think of at the moment.